# Active/Passive Reverse Proxy with nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, high-availability

I have two Websocket servers which working with `Zookeeper` & `Curator` as Active/Passive, if one server fails then second backend comes alive.

I configured it the following way:

```
upstream backend  {
  server 172.31.9.1:8080 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
  server 172.31.9.0:8080 max_fails=1 fail_timeout=5s;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    # host name to respond to
    server_name xxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.dev.xxxx.net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.dev.xxxx.net.key;

    location / {
        # switch off logging
        access_log off;

        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

What I expect is when active and passive servers switch places, Nginx will take 5 secs to recognize failure and redirect all traffic to active server.

What actually happens that it takes up to 25 seconds to recognize active server and switch all traffic.

In real scenario, I can handle up to 10 secs of downtime between redirects.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fail_timeout` from the NGINX documentation:

Sets:

- the time during which the specified number of unsuccessful attempts to communicate with the server should happen to consider the server unavailable;
- and the period of time the server will be considered unavailable.

So a setting of 5 would mean 10 seconds total (5 timing out, 5 waiting before contacting again)

By the way, the default for `max_fails` is already 1, so you don't need to set that.

---

If you actually want an Active/Passive setup, you should use this config instead:

```
upstream backend  {
  server 172.31.9.1:8080;
  server 172.31.9.0:8080 backup;
}
```